# How to connect to Postgres RDS through Postico or other client

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I've been reading this very basic tutorial from AWS: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToPostgreSQLInstance.html#USER_ConnectToPostgreSQLInstance.Troubleshooting

I opened up my Postico, copy/pasted the endpoint for my RDS database in the server field: `xxxxxxx.xxxxxx.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com`, chose port 5432, configured my username and password, and hit connect. Elas:

`Is the server running on host "xxxxxxx.xxxx.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com" (123.456.789.12) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?`

Great question, is it? Well I configured the security group to accept inbound connections from my IP on 5432, so it should be? Or am I missing something?

The RDS is created on a VPC, but I still don't understand what role it plays for my RDS instance. Isn't defining the white list for my ip enough to accept connections? What other things should I configure?

Thanks

Comment: This might not apply, but for MySQL the database user also needs to have the right to be used from an external connection.

Comment: Yes, same for the Postgres, which I also enabled ‘allow external connections’